# std::function, ошибка C2679

Tags: c++

- Kernel.h

  ```
  namespace GateServer
  {
      class CKernel
      {
          using PFMsgHandler = std::function<bool(const char * pMsg, int MsgLen)>
      public:
          bool Initialize();
          PFMsgHandler m_MsgHandler[100];
          bool OnMsgFromCS(const char * pMsg, int MsgLen);
      }
  }
  ```
- Kernel.cpp

  ```
  #include "Kernel.h"

  namespace GateServer
  {
      bool CKernel::Initialize()
      {
          m_MsgHandler[0] = &CKernel::OnMsgFromCS; //error
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```

При попытке скомпилировать программу получаю следующую ошибку:

> Error C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'bool (__thiscall GateServer::CGSKernel::* )(const
>   char *,int)' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)   GSKernel    c:\projects\с++\sonic\server\gateserver\gskernel\gskernel.cpp   28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь присвоить `std::function` указателю на член класса.

Решить проблему можно одним из двух способов:

1. Сделать `PFMsgHandler` указателем:

   ```
   namespace GateServer
   {
       class CKernel
       {
           using PFMsgHandler = bool(GateServer::*)(const char * pMsg, int MsgLen);

           // ...
   ```
2. Либо заключить указатель внутрь экземпляра `std::function`:

   ```
   #include "Kernel.h"

   namespace GateServer
   {
       bool CKernel::Initialize()
       {
           m_MsgHandler[0] = std::bind(
               &CKernel::OnMsgFromCS,
               this,
               std::placeholders::_1,
               std::placeholders::_2
           );
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Нестатические методы класса не являются обычными функциями. В частности, у каждого нестатического метода класса концептуально есть скрытый параметр `ClassType *this`.

В вашем случае метод `CKernel::OnMsgFromCS` фактически имеет *три* параметра: `CKernel *this`, `const char * pMsg` и `int MsgLen`. Вы же пытаетесь засунуть указатель на этот метод в `std::function` , у которого только *два* параметра. Поэтому и возникает ошибка.

А уж как эту ошибку исправлять зависит от того, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Есть и 3-й способ решения, для которого нужно немного видоизменить `PFMsgHandler`:

```
using PFMsgHandler = std::function<bool(CKernel&, const char * pMsg, int MsgLen)>
```

И когда будете вызывать экземпляр `PFMsgHandler` нужно будет передавать объект, для которого функция класса должна быть вызвана, например:

```
m_MsgHandler[0](*this, "Message", 0);
```

Конечно, можно в определении `PFMsgHandler` использовать указатель, а не ссылку, что будет удобнее с `this`, но будет менее удобно с объектами, которые указателями не являются.